# Hay alguna forma de imprimir directamente un reporte pdf sin abrir en el navegador y darle click a imprimir con Laravel y DompPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de punto de venta o facturación, el cual cuenta con reportes de compras y de ventas. Para generar los reportes estoy usando DOMPDF y laravel, el cual al llamar a mi función que me genera el pdf se descarga automáticamente, luego abro el archivo que se descargo y luego lo imprimo.. este proceso me parece un poco lento. ¿Hay alguna forma de configurar para que se imprima automáticamente en vez de descargarlo?

este es mi función

```
public function pdf(Request $request,$id){
    $array5 = array(); //array para almacenar el impuesto del 5%
    $array10 = array(); //array para almacenar el impuesto del 10%
    $venta = Venta::join('personas','ventas.idcliente','=','personas.id')
    ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
    ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_comprobante','ventas.serie_comprobante',
    'ventas.num_comprobante','ventas.created_at','ventas.impuesto','ventas.total',
    'ventas.estado','personas.nombre','personas.tipo_documento','personas.num_documento',
    'personas.direccion','personas.email',
    'personas.telefono','users.usuario')
    ->where('ventas.id','=',$id)
    ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();

    $detalles = DetalleVenta::join('articulos','detalle_ventas.idarticulo','=','articulos.id')
    ->select('detalle_ventas.cantidad','detalle_ventas.precio','detalle_ventas.descuento',
    'articulos.nombre as articulo', 'articulos.impuesto', 'articulos.precio_venta')
    ->where('detalle_ventas.idventa','=',$id)
    ->orderBy('detalle_ventas.id', 'desc')->get();

    foreach ($detalles as $d) {
        if ($d->impuesto == 11) {
            array_push($array10, ($d->cantidad*$d->precio-$d->descuento)/11, 5);
        } else if ($d->impuesto == 21) {
            array_push($array5, ($d->cantidad*$d->precio-$d->descuento)/21, 5);
        }
    }
    $iva5 = array_sum($array5);
    $iva10 = array_sum($array10);

    // var_dump($iva5); die;
    $numventa=Venta::select('num_comprobante')->where('id',$id)->get();

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.venta',['venta'=>$venta,'detalles'=>$detalles, 'iva5' => $iva5, 'iva10' => $iva10]);
    return $pdf->download('venta-'.$numventa[0]->num_comprobante.'.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, esto no es posible, no se puede «forzar» a un usuario de un navegador moderno a imprimir directamente algo, se requiere la intervención del mismo.

Comment: he investigado y no se puede, te muestra en el navegador para que tu lo imprimas, pero podrias agregar al iniciar el documento en jquery el codigo para imprimir la pagina, si no me equivoco me parece q es print() o algo asi, ahi te mostrata para que lo imprimas

Comment: Y como seria eso? en la vista que genera le pongo un script o como?

Comment: podrias colocarlo en el archivo donde se genera el pdf, ahi se mostrara el pdf y ahi mismo te mostrara para imprimir